# How to convert an SEO friendly URL to a PHP page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I would like to show my page URL:

```
www.mypage.com/?q=picture
```

Instead of:

```
www.mypage.com/picture.html
```

I don’t know how to redirect the page I want to see. But the url should not show page extension 
I have tried something like this but it’s not working:

```
<a href="?q=home" style="text-decoration: none; color: #1E90FF; font-size:25px;">Home</a>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q']!="" )
    {
        $ext=".php";    
        $page=$_GET['q'].$ext;
        if(file_exists($page))
        {
            header('location:$page');
        }
        else 
        {
            header('location:errorpage.php');
        }
    }    
 ?>
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with `.htaccess` I think you're looking for `mod_rewrite` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: i am not looking for any mod_rewrite.. i just want to use my code,but when i try my code it is not redirecting the page that i want.that's it

Comment: Try changing $ext to ".html"

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess. Create a file called .htaccess and add the code below. Hope this works

```
#rewrite file
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^?q=([0-9a-zA-Z]+) $1.html
```

The only problem is that i could go to www.mypage.com/?q=mario and it will look for mario.html.

If that doesn't work then uses this.

```
#rewrite file
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home home.html
RewriteRule ^picture picture.html
```

this will make www.mysite.com/picture display all the content just like viewing picture.html

Comment: I don't want to use .htaccess. anyway thanks ,looking for more answer